# Confusion regarding future scope of electrical & electronics engineering jobs (generally world wide and especially in India)

Tags: computers

This question is seeking advice generally for world wide and especially for Indian region(India and its neighbour countries having almost same economic conditions like India)

If anyone has no idea about Indian region, Its perfectly fine, just give your answer/advice for general world wide scenario

I am my self a young and new teacher in the field of electrical engineering but I am very confused if it is ethical for us to motivate youth to study electrical/electronics engineering. Please find attached a snapshot of google trends that shows comparison of electrical engineering and computer science for the last five years.

I am very confused whether we should motivate students to pursue and continue their education in field of electrical and electronics engineering. Is it really worth it, or will computer science and its related fields like AI and ML further decrease the scope/role of electrical and electronics engineerings jobs in the future?

[image]

[Link here](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&q=%2Fm%2F02lp1,%2Fm%2F01mkq,%2Fm%2F01g1rg) for the above chart.

Comment: I think the chart is a bit funny. For example, it shows almost no interest at all in electronic engineering in Germany and France, who share the bottom of the 41 regions with Croatia. Not likely. I did take notice of the fact that the uptick shown on the chart at January 1, 2022 affected electrical and computer science but had no impact on electronic engineering. They are flat-line even when all other boats are being lifted a lot (for who knows what reason.) Anyway, I'm pretty suspicious of the whole thing. But sure, I've always known it is *unethical* to encourage anyone into electronics. ;)

Comment: It seems that the chart is in the india market and it obviously doesn't hold for other countries. Many Electronics/electrical leads in other countries get paid more than software engineering leads.

Answer (score 2):

All of the fields you mention need hardware to run on. Electronics engineering will always be needed, and there are shortages in people with electronics expertise, especially in many niche areas. The ethical thing is to prep your students for the market correctly, make them learn things like PCB design and dive into its niches. Tell them that if they want to work in PCBs for example, knowing what a PCB isnt enough.

Encourage them to follow their passion, and let them know that there are many opportuinties they can get to if they work hard enough and are lucky enough to be exposed to and take opportuinties. It wont pay as much as software, but if they arent passionate in software then that doesnt matter.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which country you are and where your or others' interests lie. It may be unwise to choose something to study on the basis of market analysis as it doesn't work well. If you are in a not so advanced country, computer science may be easy and cheap to get into because computers seem available everywhere and with free software and tools, it is possible to build non trivial software if people develop skills for it.

Taking an example of a market as India in regard to your question, Electrical or electronics tools and equipment may be expensive in india for many people and also the education is focused on quick outcomes with large scale competitive tests which are cheap to do rather than doing something exhaustively practically in electrical or electronics engineering which may be expensive. People may be low skilled in electrical or electronics engineering to do anything in these fields. Many people dont transition from pre-university to university in their mindset which is why their mind is still in pre-university competitive exam realm which is sort of easy for them. The reality is like above.  Even if some people like you or others choose EEE to study,if they follow the same steps, they may not be able to do anything in it.

Answer (score 1):

The graphs you show do not state that electric and electronics fields are decreasing: they only show that the numbers are littler than computer science, but the trend seems quite stable.

As noted in other answers, electronics is everywhere, and will be always everywhere. There is and will be still the necessity of people able to cope with that, even if the numbers of those people is smaller than those in computers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there will still be some need for hardware people .I am one who is getting old .Most of the people that taught me real electronics are dead .These people were about 60 when I was about 13 .Young people do not have the theory backbone to obtain an in depth understanding of electronics. Maybe hardware depts   of the future will be small and elite.

Answer (score 0):

My crystal ball has not been that well recently, but I can offer some insights from personal experience. I started as a military tech over 30 years ago, then worked as a hardware tech/engineer for about 15 years, eventually doing analogue/mixed signal design in the 1990s, before moving in the general software direction. Embedded was a logical destination, and despite a career break of about 5 years which was hard to get out of, these days I find the demand for my skills is high. OK, all very well, but this is what I think you might learn from my experience:

1. in any tech field you have to continually evolve your skills. You can't stop learning.
2. being competent in one field is a good start, but if you can manage two that overlap you become somewhat in demand. In my case it is electronics hardware and software. For you it might be AI and economics, or maybe something in the medical/bio field. Whatever lights your candle, but combining studies that work together is a good strategy.
3. IMO experience matters more than paper qualifications. I look at my career in terms of systems or projects I delivered that work, not letters after my name. People that can and do deliver are valuable and always will be.
4. it takes time. Don't be seduced by the instant culture. Find something you really like and that you will stick with long enough to become very good at it.
5. in my case, working with experienced people that mentored me was hugely valuable earlier in my career. That allowed me to gain experience which taught me more than a degree (and which would otherwise have been hard to get access to, as I don't have one).

I hope this is not too generic or obvious, and I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

Pure computer science is in high demand, **BUT** is also a prime candidate for replacement by AI code generation, because it happens purely in the digital world.

Pure hardware electronic design is indeed becoming more niche. Much of the hardware now is digital, so programming is an implicit skill for the majority of projects now.

So I think entering *via electronics* into programming and eventually software programming is a natural course, for which one is predestined with a background in electronics. IMO the embedded programming experience, especially HDL, makes one a more complete software programmer, too. Maybe a too perfectionist one for the general webapp, but better suited for performance critical software.